# Picking a representative from $L^2$ classes of equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Strictly speaking, an element of $L^2$ is a class of equivalence whose members differ in a set of measure zero.

I am looking for a counterexample where an element of $L^2$ does not have an element that is a (piecewise) smooth function with $$f(x) = \frac 1 2 \ \lim_{a → 0} [ f(x + a) + f( x - a ) ]$$

---

I think $f \colon x ↦ θ(x) - θ(x-1)$, where $θ$ is the Heaviside theta function, might be an example of what I am looking for. It is an element of $L^2$ and there is no smooth function that differs from $f$ in a set of measure zero.

Comment: If the function is smooth, it is continuous, and thus automatically satisfies your requirement

Comment: Your formulation is a bit awkward, can you be more precise about what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Caffeine I realized the second requirement was superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a representant for which $\frac12\lim_{a\to0} f(x+a)+f(x-a)$ exists you also have a representant for which your equality holds simply by modifying that representant on the measure zero point $0$ to be equal to the limit.

So you need an $L^2$ function where $\lim_{a\to0}f(x+a)+f(x-a)$ will never exist for any representant. An example is
$$x\mapsto \begin{cases}x^{-1/4} & 0≤x≤1\\ 0&\text{else}\end{cases}.$$